# Does OpenID Connect support resource sharing

Tags: openid-connect, keycloak

Hi I'm currently looking into the possibilities of OpenID Connect. 
I've managed to find a lot of information, but for the topic of resource sharing I was not able to find that much. Hopefully someone can help me.

My question is, if the protocol supports resource sharing.
I understand that of course I can create a new resource and assign ownership tot the person I am sharing it with. This in my opinion is not a very nice solution as it polutes the resources. Is there some way to add an attribute to a resource with userId's in there which I can check for authorization.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are interested in this topic: Keycloak is planning to implement it. It is part of the specs. See jira ticket: issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-3169